# Doing same operation on multiple files

Tags: list-manipulation, import, mathematical-optimization

Is there a way in mathematica to do same operation on multiple files at once? And preferably have the output in a table or list form?

I want to do the following operation preferably in few non-labor intensive steps as possible.  (As before this, I did it allll by hand, pluggging in each number for each file. AND IT WAS NO FUN;;-( )

I have files, a001, ... a100, which contains two field(column) of numerical data that look like the following

2     4

5     6

3     7

...
..
.

For each file, I need to import/use the data in a variable in an equation and locate the global maximum which boundaries.

```
f:= Beta[2+a,4+b]Beta[5+a,6+b]Beta[3+a,7+b]......../(Beta[a,b]^n)]
```

To make the problem more complicated n is the number of rows in each file.

Next I would use NMaximize function with ristriction on 100>a>0, 100>b>0 like the following

```
 NMaximize[{Log[f], 100 > a > .1^10, 100 > b > .1^10}, {a, b}, 
 Method -> "NelderMead", MaxIterations -> 10000]
```

And if possible I would like to get the results of all NMaximize methods.

```
 NMaximize[{Log10[f], 100 > a > .1^10, 100 > b > .1^10}, {a, b}, 
 Method -> "NelderMead", MaxIterations -> 10000]

 NMaximize[{Log10[f], 100 > a > .1^10, 100 > b > .1^10}, {a, b}, 
 Method -> "DifferentialEvolution", MaxIterations -> 10000]

 NMaximize[{Log10[f], 100 > a > .1^10, 100 > b > .1^10}, {a, b}, 
 Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing", MaxIterations -> 10000]

 NMaximize[{Log10[f], 100 > a > .1^10, 100 > b > .1^10}, {a, b}, 
 Method -> "RandomSearch", MaxIterations -> 10000]
```

The wanted result would look something like this : ( header not necessary ) ( Method name not necessary, but I want 4 results for each file. )

filename    Method    a     b

f1    NM    1    4

f1    DE    .2   .5

f1    SA    .1   .5

f2    DE    .2   .3

f2    NM    1    4

f2    DE    3   4

f2    SA    .2   .1

f2    DE    .5   .6

...

..

.

PLEASE HELP. IS THIS IN ANYWAY POSSIBLE?

EDIT: [SampleData](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2t8202byj6vso8n/AACdBFy9xxaA8GhSq0IM5oKJa?dl=0)

Comment: Please put copies of three typical data files somewhere that others can download them without needing to register, log in, etc. and edit your original post to tell where you put them. Then someone can try a method and verify that it works.

Comment: Can you do this operation in an automated way for one file, if so put it in a table with all the filenames ...`Table[f[n],{n,listOfFileNames}]`

Comment: @Bill thanks hadn't thought of that. I've added link to 5 sample data files.@image_doctor If need be I can do that. Now I am working with around 100 files, but ultimately, I would have about 100,000 files. So I was wondering if it could be done automatically. If not, I guess I'll have to come up with something else later.

Comment: @agathusia Hi there, it would be automated, you would build the list of filenames using `FileNames`.

Comment: @image_doctor I am new to mathematica. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @agathusia Oliver Jennrich has reading the filenames as the first line of his solution  `files = FileNames["a*"];`. You can assume Mathematica has ways of automating everything you want to do.

Comment: @image_doctor Oh, OK. So I put the files in a Table format. What would I do afterwards? How to I handle expressing each data into the equation and how would you go about getting the results that I want?

Comment: @agathusia You may want to read some of the introductory programming material for Mathematica. It's basic data structure is the `List`. Oliver's solution builds you a list of functions, equivalent to the `f`s in your code, capable of computing the values you want. These functions are then applied to the values you want to compute using `Map`. This is typical of the functional programming style mathematica supports. Does Oliver's solution not provide the values you want, if so, in which way ? As an aside `TableForm` is just a formatting command to display a list nicely.

Comment: @image_doctor Unfortunately no. I am currently doing it manual as I gave up trying to solve the issue.  It seems like the issue comes from 'f=Function...' part. It seems like there is some issue with mapping the data. It doesn't give me the array of functions that i need but something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my quick answer.

Import the data from the files:

```
files = FileNames["/sample_data/1_5ormore_methy_00*"];
data = Import[#, "Table"] & /@ files;
```

Define a function to compute your values:

```
f[s1_, s2_, vals_] := 
   Times @@ (Beta[First@# + s1, Last@# + s2] & /@vals)/Beta[s1, s2]^Length@vals
```

Apply the function to the data for each of the desired methods:

```
res = Table[
    NMaximize[{Log[f[a, b, #]], 100 > a > .1^10, 100 > b > .1^10}, {a,
       b}, Method -> m, MaxIterations -> 10], 
     {m, {"NelderMead", "DifferentialEvolution","SimulatedAnnealing", "RandomSearch"}}] & 
    /@ data
```

Extract just the values for `a` and `b` and reshape to a list of a,b pairs:

```
Flatten[{a, b} /. #[[All, 2]] & /@ res , 1]
Export["/sample_data/1_5ormore_methy_all.csv", %]
```

Comment: Whilst you are experimenting with this you might want to drop `MaxIterations` to 10 say and maybe truncate the data to a small size by something like: `smallData = #[[1 ;; 4]] & /@ data`

Comment: Thanks! I am currently running it.  I've replaced s1_ s2_ with a_ b_. The immedieate problem I am seeing is that nnum error is showing and I think this will create some problem when Flattening. No? Is there a way to suppress nnum error? And I have worked on about 25 files now but haven't run into nnum error, so it concerns me a little.

Comment: you don't need to replace `s1` and `s2`, they are parameters allowing you to use a,b or any other symbol you like , what was your reasoning  for doing that ? :)

Comment: I changed it because I didn't know that it will allow me to use a,b in the next step. ;p

Comment: It is a variable, it will contain whatever symbol name is passed into the function :)

Comment: Thanks!! It seems like this works!!

Comment: Cheers, glad it worked out :)

Comment: If I run only only method of Nmaxizie and want to extract a,b values into a list. how would I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

Of course this is possible. But I suggest that you break the problem down in smaller steps. Let's start with the problem of reading many files. If you have them in one directory, it can be as simple as

```
   files = FileNames["a*"];
   data = Import[#,"Table"] &/@ files;
```

This fills the list data with sub-lists, that contain the data n each file.
Now you can create the expressions (no need to use functions, you can, if you want to, though) that you want to maximize

```
f = Function[u,Product[Beta[ #[[k,1]]+a, #[[k,2]]+b],{k,Length[ u] ]}]/Beta[a,b]^Length[u]] &/@ data
```

In simple words, this creates the 'Beta...Beta/Beta' function for one file. We assume that the data is stored in an array called `u`. We run through each row of the array (numbered `k`) and multiply everything (`Product`). Then we divide by the approriate power of the Beta-function  (n is here simply the number of rows in the array `u`). We run this over all the top-level components of data (i.e. over all files), which is why this is a `Function` that is then mapped (`/@`) onto the `data` array. This gives an array of expressions `f`, one for each file.

And now you can maximize:

```
max=Table[ NMaximize[{Log[#], 100 > a > .1^10, 100 > b > .1^10}, {a, b}, Method -> m, MaxIterations -> 10000], {m,{"NelderMead", "DifferentialEvolution", "SimulatedAnnealing","RandomSearch"}}] &/@ f;
```

Run the maximizer of each component of f once for each method (this is what the `Table` does, it replaces `m` by the methods one by one), yielding an array with  each of entry containing 4 solutions, one for each of the methods.

Now you just need to print them. The filename is still in `files`, so you want a table a bit like this

```
files[[1]], {a,b}/. max[[1,1]], {a,b}/. max[[1,2]], {a,b}/. max[[1,3]], {a,b}/. max[[1,4]]
.
.
.
files[[n]], {a,b}/. max[[n,1]], {a,b}/. max[[n,2]], {a,b}/. max[[n,3]], {a,b}/. max[[n,4]]
```

Use `Map` (or the `/@` shorthand) to replace all four solutions and then a MapThread to simultaneously run through the `files`

```
 tt = MapThread[ {#1 , ({a,b}/. #2 ) } & ,{files, max}];
```

Now print it:

```
TableForm[ tt];
```

Or export it into a file for future use

```
Export[ tt, "myfile.dat", "Table"];
```

Done.

Comment: Could you explain the part after the maximizing step? I run max which results in an a table of value? What do you mean to 'use Map(/@) ot replace all four solutions..."

Comment: Also it seems like for some of the files NMax is running into unidentified value problems. Is there anyway to handle this too? maybe just output an x?

Comment: And it seems like the 'f=Function..' command gives a array of {Function[u,BetaBeta/Beta]},{Function[u,BetaBeta/Beta},.. Instead of {BetaBeta/Beta,BetaBeta/Beta,BetaBeta/Beta..}

Comment: 'tt = MapThread[ {#1 ({a,b}/. #2 &) ,{files, max}];' seems like it is missing a bracket.  Since i don't quite understand the function of MapThread I don't know where to place or remove one of the brackets.